# Redo panel (F9 menu) gone forever?

Tags: edit-mode, workflow

Imagine, you add an object to the scene and you get the redo-panel (<kbd>F9</kbd> menu). If you want to modify the options of the newly created object but you mistakenly click elsewhere, the menu disappears. That's not a problem, since you can bring back this menu using <kbd>F9</kbd>.

However, imagine you move the object (using <kbd>G</kbd>) first and then want to access the <kbd>F9</kbd> menu again. When you press <kbd>F9</kbd> now, the menu of the translation will appear instead of the initial options for the object! How can I bring back the initial <kbd>F9</kbd>-menu?

Comment: Short answer: It's not possible to bring it back after the translation.

Comment: That's not the answer I was hoping for ^^ But thank you for making this clear! (I wasn't able to find the question you've linked on my own.)

Comment: Yep, I'm sorry... it is like it is...